# PHP generated Doctype problem with XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt, doctype

I am transforming XHTML to XHTML using XSLT and Doctype part is giving me problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="LimeSurvey.xslt"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
...
</html>
```

and this is not valid xml, according to IE8, FF3. Is there any way to prevent generating DOCType, xmlns from php engine? Or is there any way to make XSLT ignore DOCTYPE and xmlns?

Thanks,
Ebe

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to insert the DOCTYPE in a CDATA block [as seen here.](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N2281.html#d4160e19)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was 7 years ago, so HTML 5 now:

```
<xsl:output doctype-public="html" />
```

gives the required html 5 output...